Session timeout of developed web app deployed using azure portal after 30 min idle state
I want my session to expire after 30 minutes of inactivity. The web application can only be used after logging in with a company-based ID, i.e., a Microsoft account ID. The application is deployed on the Azure Portal.
I have implemented the following code in application.yaml. Before this, I tried multiple options available on the internet, but none were successful. I even tried deleting the cookie and session, along with various other suggestions found online, but without success.
# Session timeout
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      timeout: 30m
  session:
    cookie:
      max-age: 30m


  @Bean
    fun sessionConfig(): Session {
        val session = Session()
        session.timeout = Duration.ofMinutes(30)
        return session
    }

The session should expire. What code changes or new implementations are required? Can we configure any session timeout for a deployed web app using only the Azure Portal? If not, please suggest the necessary code changes.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Check if this solution helps.

To configure Session Timeout, Spring Security is the best choice in Spring boot application, refer the article.
This process invalidates the session after a specified period of inactivity and mitigates the security risks associated with unattended sessions and enhances the security of your application.
Configuration Class:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            )
            .headers(headers -> headers
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity(Customizer.withDefaults())
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .enableSessionUrlRewriting(false)
            );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}

I have configured Session Timeout to 30 minutes with below code:
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                  Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException, ServletException {
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1800); //30 minutes (in seconds)
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}

application.properties:
server.servlet.session.timeout=30m

Response:

